# how to show combine Array in Datatable

Tags: laravel

I am new to Laravel and trying to show combinearray in the datatable but now able to get the output.

Code for Merged Array

```
$expdataforyear= array();
$expdataforyear = array_combine($getmonths, $expdata);
```

Array Output

```
"Apr-2021" => 0
"May-2021" => 0
"Jun-2021" => 0
"Jul-2021" => 0
"Aug-2021" => 0
"Sep-2021" => 0
"Oct-2021" => "285"
"Nov-2021" => "300"
"Dec-2021" => "250"
"Jan-2022" => "180"
"Feb-2022" => "315"
"Mar-2022" => "300"
```

Datatable

```
<table id="expensetable" class="table m-0 table table-bordered table-hover table" data-order='[[ 0, "desc" ]]'>
                                      <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                          <th>Months</th>
                                          <th>Amount (Rs.)</th>
                                        </tr>
                                      </thead>
                                      <tbody>
                                        @foreach ($expdataforyearas $item )
                                          <tr> 
                                            <td>{{$item->???}}</td>
                                            <td>{{$item->???}}</td>
                                          </tr>
                                        @endforeach
                                      </tbody>
                                    </table>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: How your blade foreach loop should be: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#the-loop-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop an array in your blade by using the Blade directive `@foreach`
Inside this directive you can prinbt out. The problem in your code comes from the syntax in the foreach function. `@foreach($arr as $item) ... @endforeach`

```php
@foreach ($expdataforyearas as $itemKey => $itemValue )
  <tr> 
    <td>{{ $itemKey }}</td> 
    <td>{{ $itemValue }}</td> 
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks for Reply.... I tried that but it shown only one <td> expdata.. I need to show getmonths also in <td>.

Comment: @RahulW I updated my answer. `@foreach ($expdataforyearas as $itemKey => $itemValue )`

Comment: Thanks a Lot.... I am new to laravel so can not think about "itemKey => $itemValue"

Comment: @RahulW You welcome :-) Is similar to php foreach loop.